# Java stream: iterate two collections, chaining response

Tags: java, java-stream

I have following block, processRule() removes entries from diff list.

```
  public List<Difference> process(List<Rule> rules, List<Difference> differences) {
    for (Rule rule : rules) {
        differences = processRule(rule, differences);
    }
    return differences;
}
```

how can this be done with stream api? i can't just use flatMap because i need each new call to processRule() to have reduced `differences` as an argument.

Comment: What is `processRule` doing? Just appending to the list? Creating a new list?

Comment: *i can't just use `flatMap` because i need each new call to processRule() to have reduced differences*... please elaborate.

Comment: @Michael `processRule` transforms `diff` (actually removing items, but generally could do any). Idea is that each next `rule` processing has to be performed on an updated `diff`.  
_why do you assume_... - maybe streams are not designed for that, but i have some feeling there should exist nice solution via stream.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this using stream reduce. 
Note: not tested, posting from my mobile

```
     return rules
     .stream()
     .reduce(differences, (rule1, rule2) -> 
                             processRule(rule2, 
                             processRule(rule1, differences))
} );
```

Comment: @sab, it's not precise syntax for reduce, but if this kind of `reduce` doesn't work for you, then no other solution would. Use a loop.